# How to set height for the listview that created dynamically through java code?

Tags: java, android

I 'm trying to set the height of the listview which has been created through java code dynamically. I'm using 3 listviews(one below another) in a scrollview(to avoid hiding of lists). If i use scroll view, i cannot see all the list items of the listviews.Is there any idea to set height for those 3 list views through java coding in android? Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put ListViews in ScrollViews!  In Detail Information from the developers of Listview is available in the talk [World of ListViews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

It is possible to make the three ListViews share the space on the Screen by using the layoutWeight parameter.

Make a layout like this (you can also use code for that):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here each ListView takes a third of the available space (all weights set to 1).

To set the layoutWeight in code use this line as example:

```
listview1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Comment: even after using this coding, i could see only one list item in it.

Comment: Post your code. In my app (with a xml layout) this is working fine.

Comment: As said my @Herrmann in that Google I/O video this is mentioned in the remark by Romain Guy @ 44:14

Comment: @Herrmann Url (World of ListViews) is not working giving 404 .